# How to comment kotlin file as a class for java

Tags: java, kotlin

In kotlin xxx.kt:

```
@file:JvmName("Utils")
fun staticFunc()
```

In java xxx.java:

```
Utils.staticFunc()
```

But in java we can't see comment of class Utils because class Utils is not exist(actually it is xxx.kt), How to comment xxx.kt let java user can see comment of class Utils?

Comment: @GhostCat it is not depends on the IDE, the project will output a java-doc. I don't know where comment xxx.kt(it will compile to Utils.class)

Comment: Ah okay - now I get it...

Answer (score 4):

This is not supported. The `Utils` class does not exist from the Kotlin point of view, it's only produced for JVM interop, so there is no way to provide documentation for it.

If you need to provide documentation to Java callers, use an `object` instead:

```
/**
 * My utility functions.
 */
object Utils {
    fun staticFunc() { ... }
}
```